# How to check if the (+X) last text

Tags: lua

I have the following code:

```
local text = 'CIA'
if text == text..'+X' then
    print 'true'
else
    print 'false'
end
```

I want check if last text ends with ('+X')

Comment: I want check if last text ends with ('+X').

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [`string.sub`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.1/manual.html#pdf-string.sub) function extracts a substring. Negative indices start from the end.

```
if string.sub(text, -2) == '+X' then
     -- Ends with +X, do stuff accordingly.
end
```